# Send string unicode to servlet

Tags: android, unicode

Please help me.
I have a problem when post unicode to servlet.
Although I have tried many ways.
I send a request from android:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.ADD_REPORT_URL);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, "text/html",
            Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
// this.profile.userId));
entity.addPart(User.TOKEN,new StringBody("unicode over here"));
...
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

And in servlet

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String linkImage = "";
    if (!isMultipart) {
        System.out.println("File Not Uploaded");
    } else {
        System.err.println("A file is ready to upload");
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List items = null;
        try {
            items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            // System.out.println("items: " + items);
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Iterator itr = items.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
            // part is text form
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                System.out.println("content type:" + item.getContentType());
                String name = item.getFieldName();
                System.out.println("name: " + name);
```

but string printed `"362 Cu Giy, Dch Vng, Cu Giy,"`

Comment: What is the input and expected output